# Why does my program ignore arguments after #?

Tags: c, terminal

I'm going through Zed Shaw's 'Learn C The Hard Way' (LCTHW), and today I'm doing [exercise 14](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex14.html). [Exercise 14](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex14.html) is a simple program that prints the ASCII codes of the characters of each argument that you give when you run the program. You can view my code [here](https://github.com/jpau/LCTHW-sols/blob/master/ex14.c) (please excuse the random comments; I use this repo only to store my LCTHW notes).

My program is not running entirely as expected. I am calling the program using Terminal on OSX, and the program works fantastically until I run it using an argument that begins with '#' - that argument is ignored, as well as any after. For example, running the following command in terminal:

```
./ex14 Hello Simon #num53 okay
```

will provide only the ASCII codes for Hello Simon, but not for #num53 or okay, i.e. -

```
LCTHW-sols $ ./ex14 Hello Simon #num53 okay
Hello has 5 chars
'H' == 72 'e' == 101 'l' == 108 'l' == 108 'o' == 111 
--------------
Simon has 5 chars
'S' == 83 'i' == 105 'm' == 109 'o' == 111 'n' == 110 
--------------
```

Why is this? Further, how can I change my code so that it will accept any argument?

ex14.c copied below without my notes comments -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // Functions to classify and transform chars
#include <string.h> // for strlen()

void print_letters(char arg[]);

void print_arguments(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i = 0;

        for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) { 
                 print_letters(argv[i]);
        }
} // end print_arguments

void print_letters(char arg[])
{
        printf("%s has %lu chars\n", arg, strlen(arg));
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; arg[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                char ch = arg[i];

                // Shouldn't differ the print_arguments loop
                if(isalpha(ch) || isblank(ch) || isdigit(ch)) {
                        printf("'%c' == %d ", ch, ch);
                }
        }

        printf("\n--------------\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        print_arguments(argc, argv);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#` is a comment for many shells so the shell is probably ignoring anything after and including `#` and not passing it to your program.

Comment: +1 for providing an SSCCE.

Comment: Thank you Shafik. Your explanation is correct. For other characters such as %, the same problem does not occur. That Terminal accepts ...#... but only passes ...# seems correct :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> '#' - that argument is ignored, as well as any after.

Most UNIX shells treat `#` (and everything after it) as comment character. Your program never receives these arguments -- they are removed by shell.

Try `./ex14 '#num53'` (that is, quote the argument).

Comment: Quoting just the offending # character may also work:

    ./ex14 \#num53